# change UIImageView height with UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, height, uislider

I have 2 `UIImageViews` with a picture of a thermometer with no color and one with color. I want to set the height of the colored `UIImageView` dynamic with a `UISlider`.

So when the App starts I just want to show the thermometer without any color, when I slide my `UISlider` I want the colored `UIImageView` to increase the height. It should increase from 0 to full height(460).

How can I do that?

This is just an example of a more more complex situation.

I've tried with the following, but it just scales the whole picture, I just want to increase the height.

```
- (IBAction)my_slider:(UISlider *)sender {

    [self.thermo_color setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.value, sender.value)];

}
```

Check this link for an example photo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PARUT.jpg

Thank You.

Comment: is fixed your problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te Controller structure:

```
-MainView
--UIImageView *themFull (full image with full color)
--UIView *viewAnimated (a white view that you transform for the animation effect)
--UIImageView *themEmpty (empty Image of thermometer)
```

This Is the good way for do that:

```
- (IBAction)my_slider:(UISlider *)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.viewAnimated setFrame:CGRectMake(self.viewAnimated.frame.origin.x,
                                                self.viewAnimated.frame.origin.y,
                                                self.viewAnimated.frame.size.width,
                                                self.viewAnimated.frame.size.width / sender.value)];

    });
}
```

the size of view have to be the same of the your UIImageViews

Comment: Thanks for you contribution! But this is actually not what i'm looking for. I need to use my slider to "fill" the thermometer up.

Comment: ahhh your slider is the temperature?

Comment: Yes i have a image of a thermometer with no color at all. Then i have a image with the same thermometer but filled up with color. I want the slider to control the "temperature". So when the slider is = 0, when the image with color shouldn't appear. But when i set the slider at max it should showing the whole picture with color.

Comment: ok and how you manage the temperature? with a slider (that isn't the the thermometer with the color)

Comment: Yes i'm going to use the slider to manage the temperature. Therefor i want to use the slider.value.

Comment: ok so when your slider is 0 your temperature image is at 0 height, when you move for example the slider to 5 you have your temperature height grow up to 5, if you want that, what i write over it what you need

Comment: So let's says our slider.value = 0, then i like the thermometer to be filled 25% up with color, when my slider is = 5 i want it to be filled up with 50% of color, and when my slider is 20 i want the thermometer to be filled 100% up with color. So the higher the slider.value is, the more of the colored image should be visible.

And it's fine just if the slider also sets the height, then i can just calculate the values my self.

Comment: ok you want to manage just the transparency (so the alpha ) of you image? when your slider is at the maximum you want so see the image without transparency

Comment: Not just the transparency for the whole image, just for a small part. Please check this image:
http://i.imgur.com/z97UrRZ.jpg?1

So therefor i thought about changing the height of the colored UIImageViewer.

Comment: so you have 3 different image that you want to change step by step

Comment: Not step by step. But when I increasing my slider.value I'm also increasing the level of the temperature color.

Comment: ok, the first image that is empty is transparent where is white? If yes I edit my answer for give you the solution

Comment: Yes it's transparent. Looking forward :)

Comment: look if like that is ok for you i make the animation with a white view between the UIImageViews

Comment: That's fine. The background color dosent matter.

Comment: so with that your problem is fixed?

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot to accept it :) Thanks for your contribution.